How to properly merge meshes in geometry nodes to make new and properly welded intact faces?
I have turned a mesh (which came from a grid, where I randomly deleted some faces), into a simple N-Gon plane to join and merge back together with the previous mesh (after I delete more of its’ faces based on a minimum face area). For some reason the faces are not properly merging together to create new faces before I delete more of the faces. It is especially apparent when I turn up the probability on the 2nd delete and merge group node (I am also trying to find a way to limit the max number of faces that can be deleted at once), the faces I thought would still be there and intact disappeared. I am trying to re-mesh the plane to bigger faces, and since there are very limited ways I have found to do so in geometry nodes, any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.
I have put pictures of what I am trying to achieve and the blend file down below:











Don't have the time for executing that now, but the same selection you make for deletion can be the selection you make to extract an N-gon (like you did with the big one). Join this NGon after deletion and merge by distance (if you're not using a "selection" for deletion, but a loop that deletes face by face, join each deleted face into a new geometry to make the NGon)

@Daniel Möller I just tried a bit of this. I separated some geometry instead of deleting it and then extracted an N-gon, however, some diagonal lines appear in the mesh (I guess because some seeds give holes in the middle, which doesn't occur with the big piece). The faces given are also either small 1-unit squares spaced out or long rectangles that branch through the whole mesh. It doesn't look much like a floor plan room (maybe other restrictions might help?).
